# Beautiful Soup Not able to get_text after using extract()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am working on web scraping and i want just text from any website so i am using `Beautiful Soup`. Initially i found that `get_text()` method was also returning `JavaScript` code so to avoid i come across that i should use `extract()` method but now i have a weird problem that after extraction of `script` and `style` tag `Beautiful Soup` doesn't recognize its body even its present in new `html.

let me clear you first i was doing this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTMLRawData, 'html.parser')
print(soup.body)
```

here `print` statement was printing all `html` data
but when i do

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawData, 'html.parser')
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()    # rip it out
    print(soup.body)
```

Now its is printing `None` as element is not present but for debugging after that i did `soup.prettify()` then it print whole `html` including `body` tag and also there was no `script` and `style` tag :( now i am very confused that why its happening and if `body` is present than why its saying `None` please help thanks

and i am using Python 3 and bs4 and `rawData` is html extracted from website .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:** Using this html example:

```html
<html>
<style>just style</style>
<span>Main text.</span>
</html>
```

After extracting the *style* tag and calling get_text() it returns only the text it was supposed to remove. This due to a double newline in the html after using extract(). Call soup.contents before and after .extract() and you will see this issue.

Before *extract()*:

```
[<html>\n<style>just style</style>\n<span>Main text.</span>\n</html>]
```

After *extract()*:

```
[<html>\n\n<span>Main text.</span>\n</html>]
```

You can see the double newline between html and span. This issue brakes get_text() for some unknown reason. To validate this point remove the newlines in the example and it will work properly.

**Solutions:**

**1.-** Parse the soup again after the extract() call.

```
BeautifulSoup(str(soup), 'html.parser')
```

**2.-** Use a different parser.

```
BeautifulSoup(raw, 'html5lib')
```

**Note:** Solution #2 doesn't work if you extract two or more contiguous tags because you end up with double newline again.

**Note:** You will probably have to install this parser. Just do:

```
pip install html5lib
```

Comment: Just had this problem yesterday and was looking for an answer here

Answer (score 0):

Can you include the content of rawData?
In case your rawData is something like:

```
<script>...</script>
<script>...</script>
<style>...</style>
```

It makes sense. `X.extract()` will remove that tag from the DOM tree.

Without the entire content and your entire code it will be hard to help.

Comment: I'm not @maq, but I'm seeing the exact same behavior.  What is rawData?  Doesn't appear to be a method of `BeautifulSoup` and doesn't show up in `dir(soup)`.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't show up with `dir`, but it is an attribute.  For me, `rawData` is `None`.  But get_text() still appears to output crap that was in a script tag I extracted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the latest 4.4.0 version. I had a virtually identical problem: after decomposing (or extracting) a  tag: I could not access the next  tag.

Miguel Sanchez's first answer works, but it's very slow!

Rolling back to BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 solved the problem for me.

```
pip uninstall beautifulsoup4
pip install -Iv http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.3/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz
```